# JQuery Tabs Change Pointer onDrag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using JQuery Tabs and would like to change the pointer when I drag it.

Anyone know where to look to find out how to do that please?

Comment: `.ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-default{cursor: pointer;}` give this a go, but put it after any other css you may have on the page already on css, or you can use it on jQuery, with the `$('.ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-default').css({'cursor': 'pointer'});` white the event is triggered [ondrag event]

Comment: Thanks very much. That did it. You've written this as a comment so can I accept it as an answer? THanks BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-default{cursor: pointer;}
```

give this a go, but put it after any other css you may have on the page already on css, or you can use it on

**jQuery**

```
 $('.ui-tabs ul.ui-tabs-nav li.ui-state-default')
      .css({'cursor': 'pointer'});
```

while the event is triggered [ondrag event]